# Why am I getting a "No Match" error in csh script with standard input and output?

Tags: unix, csh

I'm trying to get a feel for Unix so that I can write a short program in UNIX csh that takes stdin and returns stdout. So I wrote the following code:

```
echo "TEST"
    echo -n "Input: "
    set TEST = "$<"
    echo $TEST
```

However I keep getting an error that I can't quite figure out when I type in certain characters. For example,

Run 1: No question mark. As you can see, it runs exactly as I want it to.

```
edoras ~/As4[199]% ./scriptp1
        TEST
        Input: www.google.com/search
        www.google.com/search
```

Run 2: With question mark. Suddenly, there's a "no match" error.

```
 edoras ~/As4[201]% ./scriptp1
    TEST
    Input: https://www.google.com/search?criteria
    echo: No match.
```

So what is this error and how do I go about fixing it? Because for the actual program I have to write I have to be able to read all special characters and print out their ASCII codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `tcsh` [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/csh):

> *Unless enclosed in `'"'` or given the `':q'` modifier the results of variable substitution may eventually be command and filename substituted.*

Since the variable is not quoted, the shell attempts filename substitution, which fails because you probably don't have a file matching `search?citeria` in a subdirectory named `www.google.com` in a subdirectory named `https:` in the current directory. "No match" means that filename substitution failed. From the same manual page:

> *It is an error for a glob-pattern containing `'*'`, `'?'`, `'['` or `'~'`, with or without `'^'`, not to match any files.*

The technical answer ends here. The rest is purely opinion-based.

Please note that unless you have specific good reasons it is usually considered preferable to write scripts in a POSIX-compatible shell, simply because `csh`-compatible shells are not always available by default. I think that as a beginner you should really first learn to write scripts in a POSIX-compatible shell and only afterwards, if needed, consider `csh`-compatible shells.

Comment: Hi Alex. I totally would do it that way, but this is an assignment and for whatever reason my professor wants us to do it in C-shell. So I don't really have a say in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

Alex is right in his answer. The "?" is one of a series of metacharacters reserved in UNIX for special commands, so in order to print them we would have to jump through some hoops that I haven't quite figured out yet. But at the very least now I know why I'm getting that output.

"?" is a matching command, so, like Alex said, it's trying to match my input to something that isn't there, instead of printing out as a plain old text character with no special value.